# How to add frequency control feedback loop to a circuit for an inductive heater

Tags: heat, feedback, high-frequency, high-current, induction

I am interested in a design made by an MIT student, Bayley Wang, several years ago for a [30kVA induction heater](http://www.instructables.com/id/30-kVA-Induction-Heater/). One engineer on this site with professional expertise examined this circuit and commented:

> One problem with the Instructables project linked : No feedback to
>   control (or limit) the frequency. With series tuned load, frequency
>   needs to be above tank resonant. The changing properties of the heated
>   load could cause tank frequency to change, and system would operate
>   below tank resonant freq. At that point, the anti-parallel diode will
>   begin dissipating a LOT of power - probably go PooF.

I emailed Bayley Wang and asked him if he agreed with this assessment and, if so, what he would recommend to do to improve the circuit and he made no response. Therefore, I am asking here how we could improve this circuit by adding a feedback loop to stabilize the frequency. The circuit is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this sort of stuff go poof. Keeping with what you have, you can do a PLL that measures phase angles with a phase comp and keeps the phase angle optimum for good resonance by changing the VCO frequency to the gate drive.

This should work; I did this in a previous life with a 4046 on a resonant mode PSU. Nowadays I prefer the self oscillating way because it's much more simple once you have got it going.

Comment: +1 for Phase Lock Loop with phase angle comparator. This method requires a C.T. or P.T. (current or potential transformer) measuring output current or coil voltage for the phase comparator input. The circuit is not trivial, and additionally it needs to assure that at startup, with no feedback signal, that the frequency begins above tank resonant frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, here's a blast from the past (in two respects!).

For background, I was among the few early-ish online / YouTube people working on induction heaters; this was ca. 2004-2010.  The design I published at the time can be found on my site: [Induction Heating Part 6](https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/tmoranwms/Elec_IndHeat6.html)

There are a number of things I would change about it, but the basic ideas are there:

- Input switch (note: should probably be a breaker), precharge circuit, contactor
- Fault protection latch, including inverter desat
- Isolated gate driver(s) (well, high side at least)
- Current, voltage and phase feedback/control
- Frequency shift controlled LLC coupling network

Contrast with the model in question (the Instructables site): it contains few if any of the features I found critical to provide.  Without any of them, it's practically a grenade with pulled pin*.

*Which is only mostly hyperbole: when a semiconductor goes off, it can in fact emit shrapnel, propelled by energy from the supply capacitor and mains fault current.  A blast shield is recommended, both to protect against that, and general arc flash.  Arc flash, is at least less of a problem for 120/240V residential/commercial circuits than it is for industrial, but it's still a concern.  If nothing else, the open-frame construction is obviously very user-unfriendly; while that might be easily cured (just add a cover), it's another simple detail that has nonetheless been omitted -- an all-too-repeating pattern in projects on sites like this.

That said, there are some issues with mine:

- Precharge circuit should monitor output, and turn off (disabling the resistors and the main contactor) if output does not stabilize within a fixed timeout period.
- More SMPS and fewer (none) iron-core transformers can be used; which I suppose might give some idea of just how long ago this was (i.e. what my level of experience was at the time), heh.  The simplest way I would recommend is, use an off-the-shelf AC-DC supply for main power (say 12V 1-2A), and DC-DC converters, or build your own flyback supply, for whatever voltages and isolation are required.  (I would recommend UC3843 over the blocking oscillator shown.)
- Control could stand to be GND referenced; both gate drivers would then need to be isolated type (and symmetrical, no one-side-transformer-coupled as here), and feedback provided via sense transformers or large-ohm divider resistors.  Then external control via DAQ or Arduino is feasible, in case that should be valuable (this is of course a common use-case in industry, such as interfacing to a PLC).
- Gate drives can use digital isolators; I later moved to SFH6345 optos, and nowadays I might go with ADuM series digital isolators, or approximately-equivalent parts from TI, SI or others.  Or whole-chip isolator-drivers, which are available with desat protection as well e.g. ACPL-330J.
- No compensation time constant is shown on the error amps (IC303) (note the fixed-gain resistors); these should be changed to relatively large R+C feedback elements, to get better setpoint accuracy.
- The half-wave / peak detect networks (e.g. D305, D306) are prone to chaotic behavior; an average-reading network is better.
- For lower power levels (say up to 1kW), isolated gate drivers aren't really necessary, and the benefit of desat protection is fairly minor; I would say a gate drive transformer is acceptable in this case (which can be driven directly by a TL598 for example, or boosted with a TC4429 or etc.).  If a mains-referenced control is acceptable, bootstrap drivers would also be suitable.  I would prefer isolated drivers with desat protection for 3kW+.
- More fault inputs, and more fault latches, can/should be used.  For example, overcurrent, overvoltage, desat, overtemp, etc.  A CD4043BE quad R-S latch is a handy way to implement this; SCRs are kind of a chintzy way to do it, honestly.
- MOSFETs have improved vastly since then; I wouldn't bother with IGBTs, except at the highest power levels (10s or 100s kW, 480V industrial modules sort of stuff).  Or SiC even.

Some of these issues were addressed by myself, internally (just that I had a bad(?) habit of not updating webpage content that I continued to improve offline), and others are kinda just how I'd prefer to deal with them today.  The exact changes are simple enough for those "skilled in the art", but aren't really well scoped to this answer so I won't explore them in further detail here.

Also the phase detector... I forget if the XOR type was actually suitable.  I think not, and that was one of the first changes in actual testing.  Let me see, the LLC output network has a 90-270° phase shift, exactly off what XOR is good at; yeah, and I changed it to a "type 2" pulse-toggled flip-flop (thus reading 25-75% Vcc for phase angles of 90-270°).  Go figure.

### Microcontroller?

One thing I definitely would *not* recommend, is implementing a control in software, especially in Arduino or other poorly-understood (by the average user) framework.  Solve all the real-time control problems in analog -- there are fewer variables and no timing constraints there, only gain and phase.

You *can (or perhaps should, even!)* use software to drive setpoints from a DAC, and read operating parameters with an ADC; the required bandwidth this way is much lower (~kHz at most?), and if the CPU skips an update cycle, or crashes or does something else unexpected, it's not a big deal, and if nothing else, has a very low chance of destroying the system.  This is a very traditional (read: 70s-90s) way of implementing digital control: start with a stable and accurate analog system, then automate around it.  It's a no less promising technique today!

### Other Design Issues

By far, the least-understood issues (personally speaking; but this most likely applies to amateurs, and many novice engineers too) were the control loop and the output network.  I won't go into still-more-excruciating detail on these topics, but suffice it to say, quite some research goes into the complete design of these systems.  While it is far from intractable, it does take a lot of experience to identify and derive/prove all the design equations, and reduce it to practice.

For further research, any of the above items would be an excellent jumping-off point; and if none can be found, they might make excellent questions to ask here.